# Lost Unity Chrome

Tags: unity

This morning, when I started up Ubuntu, it looked like the Unity design had vanished. Likewise, Google Chrome took on the platform-generic style and Pidgin became gray boxes with black frames.

[image: screenshot]

Ubuntu 14.04 32bit, latest everything. **How can I get the Unity style back?**

Comment: Try 'Settings' > 'Apperance'. What is the output of `ls -l /usr/share/themes`?

Comment: @Wilf I'm on `Radiance`. The command shows a bunch of theme files.

Comment: Changing the theme can sometimes help with things this - 'turning it off and on again' (rebooting) as well ...

Comment: @Wilf You mean reboot?

Comment: reboot just fixed it.

Comment: Shall i put 'turn it off and on again' as a answer? :)

Comment: @Wilf I guess, though it's kind of a lame answer to an irreproducible problem --- yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Turn it off and on again

Classic IT advice down the ages (thats what one I have to use does anyway...)